# Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::item()

Tags: php

The code crawls several URLs and it stops at some url with the following error:

```
 Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMElement::item()
```

Why this error is showing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably because [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) doesn't have a method named `item()`.